# Interactive selection of multiple rows of a data frame

Tags: r, menu

I have a data frame with some necessary and some unnecessary rows. I want the user to be able to determine which rows should be removed through the use of a pop-out interface.

I can do this for a single row:

```
df=data.frame(col1=letters[1:10],col2=1:10)

rm=menu(apply(df,1,paste,collapse="  "),graphics=TRUE)

df=df[!rownames(df) %in% rm,];df
```

But can't extend this to multiple rows.

I'd also be interested in hearing if there is an entirely different solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use select.list instead of menu

```
rm=select.list(apply(df,1,paste,collapse="  "),graphics=TRUE,multiple=T)
```

the output is not exactly the same , but you can have multiple selection ( with ctr + click)